# jmp instruction *%eax

Tags: assembly, x86, att

In the paper for Google Native Client, the authors define a `nacljmp` as these two instructions:

```
and   $0xffffffe0, %eax   # Clears the 5 least significant bits in %eax.
jmp   *%eax
```

First, I can see they clear the 5 least significant bits to round the pointer down to a 32-byte alignment boundary before jumping to it.  Perhaps for a tagged-pointer implementation using the low 5 bits for data.

However, what does the asterisk mean before `%eax`?

I've searched a number of tutorials on x86 assembly without much luck.

Comment: Perhaps the 32-bit data contents of the memory address pointed by the value of `eax`?

Comment: @lurker: Yes, it's an indirect jump, but it's `*%eax` without parens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`jmp    *%eax` is AT&T syntax for `jmp eax`, which is one form of `jmp r/m32`. It will jump to the address contained in register `eax`:

> Jump near, absolute indirect, address given in r/m32.

Another form of the same type of jump instruction is `jmp *(%eax)` which corresponds to `jmp [eax]` in Intel syntax. It would jump to the address stored at the 32-bit memory location pointed to by register `eax`.